# Sharing a form with multiple modules

Tags: vba, forms, module

I have a form which is to be used with different module. My issue is that the information to be obtained by the form create a "Ambiguous name detected", as the name of the variable is declared as Public within the 6 different modules. Is there a way to force the compilation, or do I have to create 6 copies of the form for each of the modules?

Comment: This sounds like a design problem.  Can you give an example of where you would get an "Ambiguous name detected" compile error?  Note that forms are classes that are instantiated as objects, so there should never be a reason to have identical copies.

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with code that depicts the general design you have, you'll get awesome answers and ideas. As it stands though, your question is rather impossible to answer without massive speculations about what you've written and how the components relate to each other. But no, there's no way to "force compilation" - you can't have ambiguous identifiers in any scope, that's just how it works.

Answer (score -1):

The quick fix is to declare the variable as global once and just have each module use it. 
A better solution is to define a property in the form to hold your valueand have each module query the property from the form